# Koa-prerender err

Tags: node.js, koa, prerender

I just installed koa-prerender and made an easy configuration

```
var prerender = require('koa-prerender');
const SITE_URL = nconf.get('services:site')
// Options
var options = {
  protocol: 'https',
  host: SITE_URL,
  prerenderToken: 'nmEKZTmqLVEHvlakX9ce'
};

app.use(prerender(options));
```

when I'm trying to get an link preview I'm getting this error

```
0|mfc  |   TypeError: query.hasOwnProperty is not a function
0|mfc  |       at shouldPreRender (/home/mfc/www/backend/node_modules/koa-prerender/index.js:104:22)
0|mfc  |       at Object.preRender (/home/mfc/www/backend/node_modules/koa-prerender/index.js:145:23)
```